# Sending Ether between two separate ethereum blockchain

Tags: blockchain, sidechain, blockchain-interoperation, swaps

is there any possible way to send ether (preferably other cryptos too) between two separate ethereum (also any other blockchains) blockchains ?
also is **HTLC support** is needed for this to be achieved?... because it does kind of resembles an **atomic swap** process.

Thank you for your answers in advance :D

Edit: would the Ethereum cross-chain swap work between a private Net and the ethereum mainnet giving that we have here two different genesis block configs (for example: the private has 0 mining rewards )

Comment: What do you mean by two separate blockchains? Do you mean two different networks?

Comment: @abed Yes , two different Networks, using the same consensus algorithm

Comment: And these two different networks are two private networks that you manage?

Comment: @abed No , only one of them is private managed by my company and the other is the Ethereum mainnet

Comment: @Ismael it could be , but what I'm asking here is "is it feasible between a private Network and the Ethereum mainnet?" the perplexing issue here is that the two networks have **different genesis block configs**

Comment: @LordGoats Yes, if you use atomic swaps.

Comment: @Ismael do you want to migrate the thread link as an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that there’s a possible way of sending ether from a private network to the mainnet. 
Because ether only have real value on the mainnet. And it’s easy to get unlimited ethers (with no value) on test networks such as Rinkeby and Ropsten.